# Why does my drop down list display “System.Data.DataRowView” instead of real values?

Tags: c#

I tried to get data in a drop down list and it's not working. I don't understand what's the problem.

```
string connString = @" Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\oshri\Documents\Stock scores.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
string queryLecturer = "select name_student from student";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
//SqlCommand cmdL = new SqlCommand(queryLecturer, conn);
conn.Open();
//SqlCommand SQLCommand = new SqlCommand();
//cmdL.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
//SQLCommand.CommandText = queryLecturer;
//conn.Close();
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryLecturer, conn);
adapter.Fill(subjects);

DropDownListID.DataSource = subjects;
DropDownListID.DataBind();

DropDownListID.DataBind();  
conn.Close();
```

Comment: What kind of control is DropDownListID? Is this a Winforms application?

Comment: WEB FORMS / MVC

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a `DataSet` containing `DataRowView` items to your drop down. Your drop down (is it a `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox`?) is not smart enough to extract the real values from this `DataSet`. Instead, use a `SqlDataReader` to read your string values and add them to a list that you can use as data source for your drop down.

```
string connString = @"Data Source=...";
string queryLecturer = "select name_student from student";
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(queryLecturer)) {
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        var list = new List<string>();
        while (reader.Read()) {
            list.Add(reader.GetString(0)); // 0 is the column index.
        }
        DropDownListID.DataSource = list;
    }
}
```

The `using` statements automatically close the connection and dispose resources at the end of the statement blocks. They do so even if the statement blocks are left prematurely because of an exception or because of a `break` or `return` statement.